# How to write ONLY ping STATISTICS to a file every hour?

Tags: ping

I'm always pinging my ISP gateway whenever I'm on my PC. My ISP likes to throttle my connection, so I have to keep a close eye on it. Is there anyway to write the ping statistics, and just the statistics to a file every hour on the hour?

EDIT: I run `ping -D 10.0.0.1` in a terminal, and I would like to be able to save only the summary or statistics that is printed whenever you press `CTRL+\` (SIGQUIT) to a file every hour. So the file would look like so:

```
[1446131810] 100/100 packets, 0% loss, min/avg/ewma/max = 1.818/3.493/3.918/4.254 ms
[1446191810] 200/200 packets, 0% loss, min/avg/ewma/max = 1.818/3.493/3.918/4.254 ms
[1446251810] 300/300 packets, 0% loss, min/avg/ewma/max = 1.818/3.493/3.918/4.254 ms
```

Comment: Can you clarify this? Please provide a sample command and sample output, and clarify which parts you want to save.

Comment: Use a utility like wireshark

Comment: What operating system are you on? On Linux you can create bash script and put it in a cron to execute every hour.

Comment: I am on linux. How would I make it to where the first ping would only run for an hour before starting the second?

Comment: So you want a ping to run non-stop and write to a log every hour?

Comment: @cakan yes, exactly. im an amateur python programmer, but im clueless when it comes to bash or shell scripting

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make a script with endless loop that will make one ping each iteration and write to a log file if there is a failure.

Take a look at this forum thread: http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=120285.0

Comment: well im not really looking to log individual packet loss. im trying to log summaries that include the average packet loss percentage over a pretty decent length of time, such as an hour or two